# Изменять значение в массиве через кнопку

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть код

```js
var all_leagues = [];

all_leagues[0] = ["Лига А", "НПЛ НСВ", "Кубок ФФА"];
all_leagues[1] = ["Бундеслига", "Первая лига", "Кубок Австрии"];

country_id.onchange = function() {
  liga_id.disabled = false;
  city_id.disabled = false;
  liga_id.innerHTML = "<option value='0'>- Выберите лигу -</option>";
  myliga = this.value - 1;
  if (myliga != -1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < all_leagues[myliga].length; i++) {
      liga_id.innerHTML += '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + all_leagues[myliga][i] + '</option>';
    }
  } else {
    liga_id.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
Страна:
<select id="country_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
  <option value="0">- выберите страну -</option>
  <option value="1">Австралия</option>        
  <option value="2">Австрия</option>
</select>

<br /><br /> Лига:
<select id="liga_id" disabled>
  <option value="0">- выберите лигу -</option>
</select>

<br /><br /> Результат:
<select id="city_id" disabled>
  <option value="0">- выберите результат -</option>
  <option value="1">Победа хозяев</option>
  <option value="2">Ничья</option>
  <option value="3">Победа гостей</option>
</select>
```

Как добавить в новый массив числовое значение, выбранного селлектора `city_id`? Т.е., если сейчас выбрать Австрию и затем Бундеслигу, а потом в селлекторе `city_id` выбрать "победа хозяев", то чтобы в новом массиве в ячейке австрийской бундеслиге в графе победы дома стояло число "1". И увеличивалось каждый раз, как выбираешь эти же селекторы и жмешь кнопку "сохранить"? Реально ли это сделать и как лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Если это голосование, то результат нужно сохранять на сервере, для этого нужен PHP. Что бы ни происходило с массивом all_leagues, всё равно после обновления страницы он будет обнуляться.

Comment: тогда буду использовать LS