# Зависимые выпадающие списки с безграничной вложенностью

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Имеется следующая структура БД:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`refid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`realid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`icon` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`translate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`keywords` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `refid` (`refid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Требуется реализовать зависимые выпадающие списки, аля Авито, т.е. вложенность может быть любая.

Самый первый список делаю следующим образом:

```
<select name="cat_id[]" id="category-0" class="form-control" onchange="select_category('0', '{$panel}');" required>
   <option value="">---</option>
   {foreach from=$acategory item=category}
   <option value="{$category.id}">{$category.name|esc}</option>
   {/foreach}
</select>
```

Последующие

```
{if $count > 0}
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <select name="cat_id[]" id="category-{$row.id}" class="form-control" onchange="select_category('{$row.id}', '{$panel}');" required>
      <option value="">---</option>
      {foreach from=$acategory item=category}
      <option value="{$category.id}">{$category.name|esc}</option>
      {/foreach}
   </select>
</div>
{/if}
```

JS

```
function select_category(refid, admin) {
    var id = $('#category-' + refid).val();
    $.ajax({
        data: {id: id, refid: refid},
        type: "POST",
        url: admin + '/category/select',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error.length > 0) { // eсли oбрaбoтчик вeрнул oшибку
                new Noty({
                    type: 'error',
                    layout: 'topRight',
                    theme: 'relax',
                    text: data['error'],
                    timeout: 2000,
                }).show();
            } else {
                if (data.count > 0) {
                    $('#category').append(data.content);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Если выбираем в правильной последовательности, то проблем нет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если попробуем перевыбрать категорию, то можем получить такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Пока что сделал такую заглушку http://joxi.ru/krD9W5Bu0PR4Dm Может кто-нибудь и напишет более адекватное решение.

Comment: при выборе пункта надо убирать все селекты, которые идут после. что-то подобное тут было -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797616/223826